# jQuery cant get parent element using .parent()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am a quite new to JavaScript and jQuery.

I am writing a website that used AJAX to update the rating of a file to the server. The idea is that when I get the response (i.e. success or failure) I should update some values of a table. However, I am having a lot of trouble because I cannot seem to be able to correctly navigate through the DOM.

The fragment of interest of my HTML is something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="some_url">some_name</a></td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>Tag</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>

    <td><button value="UP" onClick="rate(this, 'some_key', 'upvote', 'some_url' );">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style="font-size: 1.2em"></span>
        </button>
      <button value="DOWN" class="btn btn-default down_vote_button table-buttons" onClick="rate(this, 'some_key', 'downvote', 'some_url' );">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down" style="font-size: 1.2em"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
</tr>
```

My jQuery is as follows:

```
function rate(caller, key, action, action_url){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({"key": key, "action": action })
    })  
    .done(function( data ) { 
        if(action == 'upvote') {
            var upvotes = $(caller).parent("tr").eq(3).text();
            alert("upvoted: " + upvotes);
        } else if(action == 'downvote') {
            var downvotes = $(caller).parent("tr").eq(4).text();
            alert("downvoted: " + downvotes);
        }
    })  
    .fail(function( data ) { 
        alert( "File action '" + action + "' failed. Please try again later." );
    }); 
};
```

What I thought is that if there is a successful return code from the server then I pass a reference to the button that triggered the action (hence the rate(this,....) call) and then I should get the parent  of that button and finally the correct  index so that I can get the text inside. However, for some reason I never actually get the text. I tried getting just the parent of the button and I cant get it either.

Note that the table is supposed to have many entries and can vary depending on whats stored in a database.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your button has no `parent('tr')`, it's parent is a `<td>`.  An element has only one parent, the single element that it is contained in.

I suspect you want something like:

```
var upvotes = $(caller).closest("tr").find('td').eq(3).text();
```

This looks up the tree to the closest `tr` then looks within that row using `find` to locate the `td` with index = 3.

Reference : **[closest() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)**

Comment: Also check the variable assignment ... `var downvotes`, then uses `upvotes` in second alert.

Comment: @rfornal actually it uses a different variable that appears to be undefined

Comment: Correct, I suspect he meant to used `downvotes` instead of `upvoted`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This did the trick. As I said, I am new to jQuery so I thought .parent() would get the closest parent that was a <tr>.

Answer (score 0):

`parent()` only looks up ONE level. If you want to find the closest parent (not necessarily the immediate parent), use `closest()`